# JavaScript Best Practices for Scoping Event Handlers

Tags: javascript, events, scoping

I'm a Flash developer turned UX developer.  When writing event handler functions within a namespace object or class, I'm trying to figure out what the best practice would be?

I don't like it when I see some massive init function that adds nested handlers.  It's difficult to read and messy.  I think things should be broken out more.

This is how I do it (with jQuery), but is there a better more accepted way?

```
var myNamespace = {

   init: function() {

      var self = this;
      $('#button').click( function(event) { self.onClick(event); } );

   },

   onClick: function(event) {
      // do something
   }

};
```

Comment: I'd recommend taking a peek at Angular.js oder Ember.js. Those frameworks answer this question for you, following the MV* approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a new project I recommend you Backbone, it has a nice way to add events:

```
var DocumentRow = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    className: "document-row",

    events: {
        "click .icon":          "open",
        "click .button.edit":   "openEditDialog",
        "click .button.delete": "destroy"
    },

    render: function() {
        ...
    },

    open: function() {
        // listener...
    }
});
```